# Is there any way to keep validate field optional in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have User model which includes 7 fields. for all these fields validation is written.i have two form where i am displaying fields depend on condition. in one form i have name password and city and other form i have role,phone and name.

When i try to submit the first form i got the error which says phone and role field are required resulting into failure of form.

Is there any way by which i can submit both form without getting the validation errors ??

Note : i want my logic to be in model only.. Please help me with this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a conditional validation to achieve what you want:

See here:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#conditional-validation

However, this can quickly get hard to manage.  Depending on the condition you're switching on, it'd probably be a cleaner design to use a 'Form Object' which will give you more control and let you do validations without the messy conditional logic.

See section #3 of this blog post for more detail:
http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/

Using this pattern, you would check for your condition in the controller then determine which form object to send to the view.